# Why as? doesn't cast the variable inside the if block?

Tags: kotlin, casting

I wrote the folowing code:

```
 class MyRoamable
{
    var r: Roamable = Wolf()
    fun myFunction()
    {
        var x = r as? Wolf
        if (r as? Wolf != null)
        {
            r.wolfNoise()
        }
    }
}

open class Roamable
{
    fun roam():String
    {
        return "awhooooooo"
    }
}

class Wolf:Roamable()
{
    fun wolfNoise():String
    {
        return "wolf Noise"
    }
}





I can't understand why the following doesn't work:
```

if (r as? Wolf != null)
{
r.wolfNoise()
}

I'm sure that i made such a cast in the past. The error is:
**Unresolved reference: wolfNoise**

Why it's continue to treat **r** as a *Roamable* and not as a *Wolf*

The way it worked for me in the past:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    if (holder as? ViewHolder != null) {
        
        holder.homeTeamTextView.text = homeTeam
        holder.awayTeamTextView.text = awayTeam
        holder.homeTeamTextView.setTypeface(null,Typeface.NORMAL)
        holder.awayTeamTextView.setTypeface(null,Typeface.NORMAL)
        if (holder.winDescription != null)
        {
            holder.winDescription.text = gameWindowDescription
        }
        else
        {
            holder.winDescription.text = ""
        }


  class ViewHolder (view : View, onRecyclerItemClickListener: OnRecyclerItemClickListener?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
{
    val homeTeamTextView : TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.home_club_tv)
    val awayTeamTextView : TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.away_club_tv)
    val homeTeamImageView : ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.home_club_iv)
    val awayTeamImageView : ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.away_club_iv)
    val timeTextView : TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.games_status_tv)
    val scoreTextView : TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.score_tv)
    val winDescription: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.game_window_description)
```

i could get all the data from the views since
if (holder as? ViewHolder != null)  succeeded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Smart casts don't just happen, every pattern has to be explicitly supported in the compiler. If you make `r` a local variable

```
fun myFunction() {
    var r: Roamable = Wolf()
    if (r as? Wolf != null) {
        r.wolfNoise()
    }
}
```

or a `val`

```
val r: Roamable = Wolf()
fun myFunction() {
    if (r as? Wolf != null) {
        r.wolfNoise()
    }
}
```

it works.

Parameters are treated like `val` local variables in this respect, so the `override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int)` example is actually both.

In your case, if an instance of `Roamable` was visible to two threads, and one of them executed `myFunction`, the other one could change `r` after `r as? Wolf` was evaluated and before `r.wolfNoise()` was.

You could say: but this program doesn't have any threads! But the compiler has to compile `Roamable` so it can be used in other programs as well.

EDIT: I somehow misread your example and thought you had

```
var r: Roamable = Wolf()
fun myFunction() {
    var x = r as? Wolf
    if (r as? Wolf != null) {
        r.wolfNoise()
    }
}
```

inside a function, not a class. The below explanation would apply in that case.

If you use a local variable (not a property!) `var` from outer scope in a [local function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#local-functions), as in

```
fun outer() {
    var r: Roamable = Wolf()
    fun myFunction() {
        var x = r as? Wolf
        if (r as? Wolf != null) {
            r.wolfNoise()
        }
    }
}
```

the compiler has to turn it into something like

```
private class RoamableHolder(var value: Roamable)

private fun outer_myFunction(holder: RoamableHolder) {
    if (holder.value as? Wolf != null) {
        holder.value.wolfNoise()
    }
}

fun outer() {
    val r_holder = RoamableHolder(Wolf())
    outer_myFunction(r_holder)
}
```

behind the scenes, because JVM doesn't have local methods. You can see how it would allow `myFunction` to change the value of `r` and make this visible afterwards in `outer`.

The smart cast wouldn't work with that code, because you can't smart-cast `var` properties, so it doesn't work with the original code either.

But if `r` in `outer` was a `val` instead of `var`, there's no need for `RoamableHolder` and the translation is simpler:

```
private fun outer_myFunction(r: Roamable) {
    if (r as? Wolf != null) {
        r.wolfNoise()
    }
}

fun outer() {
    val r: Roamable = Wolf()
    outer_myFunction(r)
}
```

Comment: is there a logic behind it or it just a compiler "rules"? I guess it is related to the fact that local variable can't be changed by another function

Comment: I tried to explain in more detail (see "If you use a non-local var in a function..."). Probably this case can be supported with some effort by compiler developers, but they haven't done it yet.

Comment: you wrote : `behind the scenes` but actually it is the code that i'm as a programmer writing. I don't see here any `behind the scenes` :)

Comment: Ok, sorry, I somehow managed to misread your example, so the actual answer is simpler (and the cast can't be supported without breaking separate compilation completely).

Comment: unfortunately i have difficult to understand your two last examples. If you can, it will help if you say: `if you use a local variable (not a property!) var from outer scope in a local function, the compiler has to turn it into something like` to which local variable you mean in your example... same if for the `non-local val` in the last example.. Can't understand both examples although i think it's not critical

Comment: thanks it is better now! but i can't understand how my original question related to outer and inner function

Comment: As I said: I simply didn't look carefully enough and thought that was the code you had!

Answer (score 1):

In your Roamable example, `r` is a property. A `var` property can never be smart-cast because the compiler can't guarantee the property will return the same value in between when you type-check it and when you try to do something with it (call its functions, pass it as a parameter, assign it to a variable, etc.). This is also true of `val` properties with custom getters.

Now maybe you aren't using this class in a multi-threaded way so you know the cast would be safe, but the compiler isn't smart enough to check for that, so you have to manually cast. I think the reason for this compiler rule is that it is too complicated to check. Maybe it's feasible, but some compiler limitations were put in place so compiling will be fast, not because of logical impossibility.

In the ViewHolder example, `holder` is a function parameter, so it is not possible for some other thread to modify it. In Kotlin, unlike Java, function parameters are constants so it's not possible to modify them at all. So smart-casts are always possible with function parameters.

You can also smart-cast with local `var` variables, since the compiler can see in the local code that the variable hasn't been reassigned in between your check and your use of the value. If you use the local variable in a closure, then it is no longer smart-castable, because now it's kind of like a property: it can be modified from somewhere else, so the compiler can no longer make guarantees about its type.

Comment: can you explain the two things: 1. `This is also true of val properties with custom getters.` 
2. `If you use the local variable in a closure, then it is no longer smart-castable, because now it's kind of like a property`

Comment: 1. A `val` property can be smart-cast, unless it has a custom getter. 2. Usually, a local `var` can be smart cast. But if it is modified in some lambda or interface implementation that you create in the local function, then it is captured in that closure. The compiler can no longer guarantee it won't be modified by code outside the local function, so that variable cannot be smart cast, just like how a `var` property cannot be smart-cast.

Comment: 1.How custom getter can make "problems"?

Comment: Or maybe i'm still in low level and shouldn't think about extreme cases?

Comment: A custom getter could return a different value each time you access it.

Comment: is it ok from your side that i will open a question about the way local function can affect a local var because i didn't understand it and really want to understand

Answer (score 0):

Too complex for the Kotlin's compiler :) I think it will be more idiomatic to write like this:

```kotlin
fun myFunction() {
    val x = r as? Wolf
    x?.wolfNoise()
}
```

In your example with view holder you don't cast variable. You just check it for null

Comment: Tanana, if i didn't cast so `homeTeamTextView` , `awayTeamTextView`, `etc` are  recognized?

Comment: I'm not totally sure but looks like you use kotlin extensions. It works in some other way. You can try to remove your `if` and check

Comment: You mean to remove it with the `ViewHolder` code? if yes, so i tried and the fields of the `ViewHolder` aren't recognized anymore

Comment: wow, that's cool. It really works with view holders somehow

Comment: "It really works with view holders somehow" With function parameters, rather.

Comment: yes, I've just realised that. Variable can be changed in any time so we cannot rely on cast check